# Make user class in laravel without a database

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 to retrieve data from an api and display it in a website.

The api returns the auth user every time I send any request with a JWT token in the header.

When the user has signed in once, I send the token in every request.

I want a way in which I can check auth user and its details in every view.

1) How do I set the response to the User class so that I can use it later in the views as a Facade?

2) How do I retrieve the auth user?

3) How do check if there is a auth user or not?

A response is in Json

```
  "feed": {...}
  "auth": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hetu Nandu",
    "title": "Student",
    "kp": 43,

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to **Auth::user()** returns currently authenticated user. As you want to re-use existing authentication functionality with a remote user storage you'll need to do a couple of things.

First, you'll need a User class that will be used for authentication. It needs to implement **Authenticatable** interface. The only method from this interface you need is **getAuthIdentifier()** - it should return unique identifier of given user. This identifier is saved in session and later used to reload used data for subsequent requests. You could return the **JWT token**.

Next, you need to authenticate a user in Laravel. You can do it with

```
Auth::login($user)
```

This will store user's identifier in session.

Finally, you need a way to load user data for subsequent requests. You'll need to implement custom user provider - it's fairly simple. You can find an example in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#adding-custom-authentication-drivers

Comment: So the $user passed in the method will be the token?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User
{
 use Authenticatable;


 public function getAuthIdentifier()
 {
  return Request::cookie('token');
 }


}`

Comment: It needs to be the user object.

Comment: So I am able to log user in with Auth::login($user) but i am still having issues with the userprovider. If i am right, this class will pull the data from the response and suply it to auth class right? which method should i use for my case? I am feeling like a real noob here :|

Comment: Doesnt the API you use provide some client library? If not have a look at guzzle library